# How to create dir with special characters in Android

Tags: java, android, special-characters, mkdir, mkdirs

I need to create a folder named `.ext.maps_common@transit` etc. (untar archieve at other folder), I tried to use `mkdir ()`, `mkdirs ()`, trailing slash at its end and so on, but with no results. My final code is quite simple:

```
File dir = new File (".ext.maps_common@transit");
if (!dir.isDirectory ()) dir.mkdirs ();
```

Is it really to do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: It's quite simple: `File dir = new File (".ext.maps_common@transit"); if (!dir.isDirectory ()) dir.mkdirs ();` Add it at my question.

Comment: where are you trying to make this directory? at which location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
 File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ".ext.maps_common@transit");
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
```

and change `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to wherever location you want to create the directory. Don't forget to add neccessery permissions.

Comment: Thanks, seems it working all this time, but not shown in my file explorer. It was nessessary for me to reboot it to see it. So strange...